# Multiple Quotes in one syntax using Python

Tags: linux, windows, bash, winexe

Im using raspberry pi and i want to control another windows machine by sending command using winexe. i can use the command directly from the terminal. However if i use python to send the command, the command seems invalid.

i can run this command at the terminal with no problem

```
 winexe -U pc1%ppc1 //ipaddress 'netsh interface show interface'
```

i know its not practical to use os.system but the syntax works fine for me if use it with python

```
 os.system('winexe -U pc1%ppc1 //ipaddress "netsh interface show interface"')
```

when i want to quote another syntax. with the terminal i run it and it works perfectly fine

```
 winexe -U pc1%ppc1 //ipaddress 'netsh interface set interface "Local Area Connection admin=disable'
```

How can i use python to run the syntax for above line? i have already tried with

```
 os.system('winexe -U pc1%ppc1 //ipaddress "netsh interface set interface "Local Area Connection" admin=disable"')
```

but the code cant run its just loading forever. its like i quote it wrongly. anyway to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You have not said exactly what error it gives you, however

i think the problem could be that you try to use 3 nested quotes

```
'  " " " " '
```

but you should use a third type of quote (`) to make it works

```
'  "  ` ` " '
```

so

```
os.system('winexe -U pc1%ppc1 //ipaddress "netsh interface set interface `Local Area Connection` admin=disable"')
```

Comment: using above code, it detect my code start from winexe and finish until set interface. it totally ignore Local Area Connection syntax

Comment: have you try this? os.system(\`winexe -U pc1%ppc1 //ipaddress 'netsh interface set interface "Local Area Connection" admin=disable'\`). Maybe the netsh command does not handle the ` quote.

Comment: still not working. it just prompt me to use correct syntax with winexe

Comment: as a last idea I would try to use the subprocess module ( https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) to send pars separately.

Comment: actually i have already tried subprocess but with subprocess, it says login invalid